# How to fetch only some rows from a SqlDataReader?

Tags: c#, linq, fetch, datareader

i'm fetching values from a table with datareader like this:

```
    string query = @"SELECT XMLConfig, Enable FROM TableCfg";
    using (SqlConnection cnction = new SqlConnection(cnnstr))
    {
      cnction.Open();
      using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnction))
      {
         SqlDataReader dtRead = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
         while (dtRead.Read())
         {
           xmlConf = dtRead.GetString(0);
           enabl = dtRead.GetString(1);
         }
         dtRead.Close();
      }
    }
```

The Enable field is a boolean(True/False). Is there a way to fetch only the rows, where field enable="True"?
I tried using LINQ, but i'm new to this and i must be doing something wrong.

```
using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnction))
{
  SqlDataReader dtRead = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
  var ob =(from IDataRecord r in sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
           where r.GetString(3).ToString() == "True"
           select "Enable");   
}
```

Help me please.
Best Regards.

Comment: "The Enable field is a boolean(True/False). Is there a way to fetch only the rows, where field enable="True"?" - why don't you just add that as a WHERE clause in the SQL?

Answer (score 7):

You should really do as much filtering as possible at the database side rather than client-side:

```
string query = "SELECT XMLConfig FROM TableCfg WHERE Enable = True";
```

Notice how now you don't even need to fetch `Enable`, as you already know it will be `True` for all the matching rows.

You should also consider using LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework rather than the rather low-level stack you're currently using. It's not *always* appropriate, but it does make things cleaner where it's suitable.

Comment: I could try to find something to cover up why i asked this (now) stupid question, but the truth is that i'm tired and this never cross through my mind. Thanks for the patience. This solved my problem.